# Android Universal Image Loader - how do I set the specs correctly?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, universal-image-loader

I have an app that loads a lot of big images remotely.
When I use nostra's Universal Image Loader (https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) I often get Out Of Memory errors. I don't know how I should set up the imageloader to prevent this.

This is my current ImageLoader specs:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .enableLogging()
        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
        .build(); 

this.imgDispOpts = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory() 
        .cacheOnDisc() 
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT) 
        .build();

this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
this.imageLoader.init(config);
```

And yes, I pass imgDispOpts when calling displayImage().

Answer (score 5):

Try not cache in memory, use `EXACTLY` scale type and `RGB_565` for bitmap decoding.

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .enableLogging()
    .build(); 

this.imgDispOpts = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() 
    .cacheOnDisc() 
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) 
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reduce the bitmap size in the bitmap decoder, which worked for me.

In package com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.decode, open BaseImageDecoder.java,

```
public Bitmap decode(ImageDecodingInfo decodingInfo) throws IOException {
        Bitmap decodedBitmap;
        ImageFileInfo imageInfo;

        InputStream imageStream = getImageStream(decodingInfo);
        try {
            imageInfo = defineImageSizeAndRotation(imageStream, decodingInfo);
            imageStream = resetStream(imageStream, decodingInfo);
            Options decodingOptions = prepareDecodingOptions(imageInfo.imageSize, decodingInfo);

// add in the decodingOptions here:

decodingOptions.inSampleSize = 10; // or any number

// or you can calculate the resample rate by using the screen size / grid size and the image size

decodedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, decodingOptions);
    } finally {
        IoUtils.closeSilently(imageStream);
    }
    if (decodedBitmap == null) {
        L.e(ERROR_CANT_DECODE_IMAGE, decodingInfo.getImageKey());
    } else {
        decodedBitmap = considerExactScaleAndOrientaiton(decodedBitmap, decodingInfo, imageInfo.exif.rotation, imageInfo.exif.flipHorizontal);
    }
    return decodedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks alot! Out of memory exception had driven me mad.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below configuration

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
    .enableLogging()
     discCacheExtraOptions(maxImageWidthForDiscCache, maxImageHeightForDiscCache, CompressFormat.PNG, 0);
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .build();

 this.imgDispOpts = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory() 
    .cacheOnDisc() 
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY) 
    .build();
```

You can also use Lazy Loading of images.https://github.com/thest1/LazyList.

Universal Image loader based on Fedor Vlasov's project LazyList. Improved version of LazyList.

Comment: what is the work of this line,
discCacheExtraOptions(maxImageWidthForDiscCache, maxImageHeightForDiscCache, CompressFormat.PNG, 0);

Comment: for caching of bitmaps with proper height and width setting the max height and width

Comment: Is it can be effect on Image quality if we set the static height and width ?

Comment: set the image  height and width to your desired value to reduce out of memory error. if the image is too large to fit in memory you will run into oom error

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, it worked well for me:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
//Add these lines to your ImageLoader configuration
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2);
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory();
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(150, 150, null); // You may change image resolution to fit your needs


ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config.build());
```